# Make my window first responder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I need to launch my application without windows, but when an error occurs I need to display the error in a window. My problem is that I can't make my window as first responder, so the windows buttons aren't working because the window is not in focus.
I created a window and its controller. The button have the action defined.
Any ideas?
This is my source code:

```
@interface ErrorWindow : NSWindowController {
    IBOutlet NSImageView *_imageView;
    IBOutlet NSTextField *_message_text;
    IBOutlet NSTextField *_informative_text;
    IBOutlet NSWindow *_errorWindow;

}

- (IBAction)closeWindowAction:(id)sender;
```

In my implementation:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {

    [_errorWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
    [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
}
```

Comment: if you're bringing up an error window... why couldn't you give it focus (via `makeKeyAndOrderFront` ?)

Comment: this is my code but is not giving the focus to my error window,     [_errorWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];

Comment: Modify your original question to show more than just those two lines here in a comment. I think there's a bit more going on (e.g. is _errorWindow valid?). And your problem is that the window appears but the buttons don't respond?

Comment: exactly, the error window appears, but the main window and the error windows don't respond to any action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the problem is that you are calling `[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];` after displaying the window. Have you tried reversing the order?

Comment: I tried changing the oden, but I still have the same problem. Is it because my main window is not closed? I have the error window and the main window open at the same time.